# Get the first category assigned to a WordPress post but ignore certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories

My WordPress project has a couple of categories that are used internally only and I don't want them to be picked up on the front end. This causes problems when I want to display the first category assigned to a post.

What I'm trying to do is loop through the assigned categories using `get_the_category` until I reach a category that is not **Uncategorised** or **Event**. I've tried using `continue` and `break` without success.

```php
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    foreach( $categories as $category ) :
        $category_name = $category->cat_name;
        if ( $category_name == 'Uncategorised' || $category_name == 'Event' ) continue;
        $category = esc_html( $category_name );
        break;
    endforeach;
}
echo $category;
```

I expected this to display the first category name that is **not** *Uncategorised* or *Event* as a string, though I've had inconsistent results, with it returning objects and even the unwanted names. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I ended up using this:

```php
$categories = get_the_category();
if( $categories ) {
    foreach( $categories as $category ) :
        $category_name = $category->cat_name;
        if ( $category_name == 'Uncategorised' || $category_name == 'Event' ) continue;
            $category = esc_html( $category_name );
            break;
    endforeach;
    if( ! is_string( $category ) ) {
        $category = null;
    }
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure it could be done in a less verbose way and I'm also unsure about the non-string result which occurs if neither of the two  excluded categories are found. I'd still be grateful for some expert opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Your don't break foreach loop correctly:

```php
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $category_ok = '';
    foreach( $categories as $key => $category ) :
        $category_name = $category->cat_name;
        if ( $category_name !== 'Uncategorised' && $category_name !== 'Event' ) {
            $category_ok = esc_html( $category_name );
            break;
        }
    endforeach;
}
echo $category_ok;
```

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately, neither category was successfully filtered out.

Comment: I modified my answer. Are you sure names 'Uncategorised' and 'Event' are well writen?